# create an array of objects in the computed method vuejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I already appreciate your advice and answers, this time I go to you for the next problem I pass context, I want to create a dynamic table with quasar and vueJS this table will change according to a select field I have managed to bring the columns of the Selected tables, what I can't do is paint them in the view, since for this I must generate the following structure to be able to paint the table:

```
 columns: [
         {
           name: 'id', align: 'center', label: 'id', field: 'id'
         },
         {
           name: 'name', align: 'center', label: 'name', field: 'name'
         },
         {
           name: 'age', align: 'center', label: 'age', field: 'age'
         }
       ]
     }
```

I want to form the structure above from an array that comes to me from the database (the columns of the table), what I receive is the following:

```
const columnsTable = [
   "id",
   "name",
   "age"
];
```

I am trying as follows in my computed method:
[My computed method to generate the array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVtNn.png)
The result of this is not what was expected since in each key of my object the entire array is entered in this way.
[colums in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLMGF.png)
The variable colums is where I want to generate the array of objects described at the beginning of the question.
I appreciate your answers and opinions, anything would help me a lot, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like following snippet:

```js
const columnsTable = [
   "id",
   "name",
   "age"
];
const res = []
columnsTable.forEach(c => {
  res.push({name: c, align: 'center', label: c, field: c})
})
console.log(res)
```